# webpack multiple outputs for same input

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less, webpack

I need to process all .less files using webpack (can't do it with other tools like gulp, because those .less files could be in referenced npm modules).
I have to process twice those .less files:

- First transformation: .less -> remove all dynamic rules -> compile to css -> save to .css bundle
- Second transformation: .less -> remove all static rules -> save to .less bundle

here is the config I'm trying to do:

```js
var cssExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].bundle.css", { allChunks: true });
var lessExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].bundle.less", { allChunks: true });
```

```js
  module: {
   loaders: [

    { test: /\.css/, loader: cssExtract.extract("style", "css") }, 
    
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: lessExtract.extract("raw!less-theme") }, // dynamic less
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: cssExtract.extract("style", "css!less!less-static") }, // static less
```

If I activate one ./.less$/ test it will do the job but I can't activate both /.less$/ tests (only one will be executed).
Here are my constraints:

- don't want to execute webpack twice, I don't want to double build duration.
- can't use gulp or any other build tool. since my project is referencing other .less files located in npm modules (node_modules).

Comment: Could you not write your own node build script and then package the output to your webpack bundle? Webpack is good for bundling code and resolving dependencies on the client side, but doesn't really work as a build tool.

Comment: if I do so, I will re-implement all the dependency resolution mechanism of webpack, in order to find referenced ".less" files.